# GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'Lenght Im trying to make dodge game and making a spawner for it but i get this error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have hazards tht is enemy falling from top but im getting GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'Lenght error here is the code:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public Transform[] spawnPoints;
 public GameObject[] hazards;

 private float timeBtwSpawns;
 private float startTimeBtwSpawns;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     

     if(timeBtwSpawns <= 0)
     {
      Transform randomSpawnPoint = spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)];
      GameObject randomHazard = hazards[Random.Range(0, hazards.Lenght)];

      Instantiate(randomHazard, randomSpawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

      timeBtwSpawns = startTimeBtwSpawns;
     }

     else
     {
         timeBtwSpawns -= Time.deltaTime;
     }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lenght` should be spelled `Length`

```cs
                                                             ↓↓↓
GameObject randomHazard = hazards[Random.Range(0, hazards.Lenght)];
```

should be

```cs
                                                             ↓↓↓
GameObject randomHazard = hazards[Random.Range(0, hazards.Length)];
```

`Quarternion.identity` should have it's assembly explicitly referenced. You can remove the ambiguity of this call by using `UnityEngine.Quarternion.identity` instead.

Comment: thank u for helping i got one more error on 30th line too quaternion error

Comment: the correct reaction to this question would've been a comment, and a flag as "caused by a typo"

Comment: Wow, you're totally right! I checked the flag options and there wasn't any mention of typographical errors, so I was confused initially. It took some digging through the help center but I did find that! It was under [What topics can I ask about here, #2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in case others need it. It doesn't have it's own flag, but we would chose Needs Improvement > Community Specific reason. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.